# Getting IAM token using curl fails

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have been trying to generate an IBM Cloud IAM token using the following command:

```
 curl -ik -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "Accept: application/json" --data-urlencod
e "grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey" --data-urlencode "apikey=rzQV6ahSbPLzXjzhzuAEtbXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" --data-urlencode "response_type=cloud_iam,uaa&uaa_client_id=cf&uaa_client_secret=" "https://iam.ng.bluemix.net/oidc/passcode"
```

But it keeps giving me 405 method not allowed. What is the right way to generate the token? Is there any documentation which could be followed?

Comment: Isn't https://iam.ng.bluemix.net/oidc/passcode a human-intended web page and not an API endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the endpoint you are using. Here's the working `curl` command to generate an IBM Cloud IAM token

```
 curl -ik -X POST \
  --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --data-urlencode "grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey" \
  --data-urlencode "apikey=<APIKEY>" \
  "https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token"
```

You can generate an IAM token by using either your [IBM Cloud API key](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/userid_keys.html#userapikey) or a [service ID's API key](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/serviceid_keys.html#serviceidapikeys).

Here's the [link to the documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/apikey_iamtoken.html#iamtoken_from_apikey)